# Generate MAC address with VBA (format xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to generate the MAC Address format like this 00:06:9C:10:07:45 but, I have the condition is 
 -

- MAC address should be unique (Not duplicate with the existing MAC address)>
- Need to count continue from the last MAC such as the last MAC is 00:06:9C:10:07:01 the next MAC should be 00:06:9C:10:07:02.....nn:nn:nn:nn:nn:nn (the last MAC it has on same workbook different sheet).
- The new MAC needs to record continue with the last MAC also. and need to export to CSV file(Just the new MAC does not include the old one)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()  'Get the last MAC Address function
    Dim var As String


    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long



        lRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=Range("A1"), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row

        var = Range("A" & lRow).Value
        MsgBox "Last value is : " & var

    End Sub

    Private Sub exportText_Click()

            Dim i As Integer
            Dim MacStd As String


            MacStd = "00:06:9C:10"

                  For i = TextBox1 To TextBox3

                Cells(i, 1).Value = MacStd & ":" & Hex(i)
            Next i
        'MsgBox Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Select
    End Sub
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Do not tag multiple languages. Tag **only** what is relevant to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tray the next code, please. It returns in Immediate Window (Ctrl + G, in VBE), but it can easily adapted to return whenever you need. The code can be done in a more elegant recursive way using a public variable, but no time to invest in this aspect...

Create the next variables, on top of your module, on the declaration area:

```
Option Explicit
Private finishVal As Long, curMAC As Long, boolStop As Boolean, boolFirst As Boolean
```

Then, copy the next Subs:

```
Sub testMACGenerator() 'used to test the MAC creation
    Dim MacLast As String, startVal As Long
    finishVal = 1500 'how many MAC addresses to be created
    curMAC = 0: boolStop = False
    MacLast = "00:06:9C:10:01:01" 'Starting MAC (last recorded MAC)
    'the above one uses your root ("00:06:9C:10") and first Hex values for
    'the fifth and the sixth groups
    MACGenerator1 MacLast
End Sub

Private Sub MACGenerator1(strMAC As String)'creates the fifth MAC group
 Dim i As Integer, macIntermed As String, j As Long, MacStd As String
 Dim startVal As Long, startSec As Long
    MacStd = left(strMAC, 11)
    startVal = CLng("&H" & Split(strMAC, ":")(4))
    startSec = CLng("&H" & Split(strMAC, ":")(5)) + 1: boolFirst = True
    For i = startVal To 255
        If boolStop Then Exit Sub
        If IsNumeric(Hex(i)) Then
            macIntermed = MacStd & ":" & Format(Hex(i), "00")
        Else
            If Len(Hex(i)) = 1 Then
                macIntermed = MacStd & ":" & "0" & Hex(i)
            Else
                macIntermed = MacStd & ":" & Hex(i)
            End If
        End If
        If boolFirst Then
            MACGenerator2 macIntermed, startSec
        Else
            MACGenerator2 macIntermed
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
'it creates the sixth MAC group:
Private Sub MACGenerator2(MacStd As String, Optional lngFirst As Long)
 Dim i As Integer, macFinal As String, j As Long
    For i = IIf(lngFirst <> 0, lngFirst, 1) To 255
        If IsNumeric(Hex(i)) Then
            macFinal = MacStd & ":" & Format(Hex(i), "00")
        Else
            If Len(Hex(i)) = 1 Then
                macFinal = MacStd & ":" & "0" & Hex(i)
            Else
                macFinal = MacStd & ":" & Hex(i)
            End If
        End If
        curMAC = curMAC + 1
        Debug.Print macFinal ': Stop
        If curMAC >= finishVal Then
            boolStop = True
            curMAC = 0: finishVal = 0
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
    boolFirst = False
End Sub
```

If something unclear, do not hesitate to ask for clarification.

Comment: Thank very much. It very helpfully for me